# Spring MVC and Thymeleaf - only classpath mapping works

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I wonder why I have to add "classpath:" always int he resourcelocations mapping for Spring, is this best practice?

Currently my project is setup like this, but I if I remove the "classpath", it does not find anything (and also I cannot provide a proper direct link). For integating bootstrap, I even had to use "webjars-locator" to make webjars accessible (due to missing transparency).

Can anyone explain, why classpath is required (and no direct link), and how I can find or restrucutre the project to make it work properly?

ResourceHandlers:
@Override

```
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/webjars/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**")
        .addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/",
                "classpath:/static/img/",
                "classpath:/static/css/",
                        "classpath:/static/js/");

    }
```

index.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
<title>Spring Security Example</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />

</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="color1">Hello, world! style</h1>

    <p>
        Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.
    </p>


    <!-- include javascript in the footer -->
    **<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>**
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to use classpath.  If you want to additionally load resources from root path use

```
{"/", "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" ...}
```